# java any class for temperature?

Tags: java

I am trying to write a code for checking the temperature every hour. 
there is a class like java.util.Calendar; that gets us months and hours and seconds but is there any class for getting temperature? 
Thanks for help.

Comment: Your computer has a clock, but does it have a thermometer?

Comment: Yes -- one you write yourself.

Comment: @Kayaman Doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: Unlike for time, to get external temperature you need a sensor. Most computers aren't going to have one installed by default so...

Comment: Which temperature?

Comment: @takendarkk My laptop has seven.

Comment: @chrylis But I bet none of those can tell you how hot it is outside right now.

Comment: @Kayaman Not outside, but they'll certainly "get temperature".

Comment: @chrylis Certainly, but considering the reference to `Calendar` it seems more likely to refer to "natural" temperature instead of CPU temperature. However until he elaborates on what he's looking for, it's all guessing.

Answer (score 0):

There are some libraries available such as [JScience](http://jscience.org/), but there's no class for temperature measurements included in the JDK. In a case like this, where you need at most conversion between Fahrenheit and Celsius, I suggest you write your own, or just use a double.